# Template for both structures and functions?

Tags: c++, templates

Please, look at this short function:

```
void SEMTools::pack_CT_CMD(CT_CMD_t cmd)
{
    QByteArray payload(8, 0);
    uint8_t len, ide;
    int txId = Pack_CT_CMD_can(&cmd, reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(payload.data()), &len, &ide);
    QCanBusFrame txFrame = QCanBusFrame(txId, payload);
    _can->sendFrame(txFrame);
}
```

I need about 20 of this "template" function, where the only things that change are:

- `CT_CMD_t`, it's a structure, and I have 20 different structures
- `Pack_CT_CMD_can`, it's a function, and I have 20 different structures

My goal is to write only one function like this (meta code):

```
void SEMTools::pack_CMD(<generic-struct> cmd, <generic-func> func)
{
    QByteArray payload(8, 0);
    uint8_t len, ide;
    int txId = func(&cmd, reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(payload.data()), &len, &ide);
    QCanBusFrame txFrame = QCanBusFrame(txId, payload);
    _can->sendFrame(txFrame);
}
```

Then, I would use in this way (still meta code):

```
CT_CMD_t cmd1;
AB_CMD_t cmd2;

Pack_CT_CMD_can func1;
Pack_AB_CMD_can func2;

pack_CMD(cmd1, func1);
pack_CMD(cmd2, func2);
```

I'm not sure if the use of a `template` is the correct approach here, or there is something better.

Comment: You have 20 structures and 20 functions, do they need to match, or the same structure can be used with any functions?

Comment: Each struct matches its related function. They cannot be mixed.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a template with 2 parameters:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void SEMTools::pack_CMD(T cmd, U func)
{
    QByteArray payload(8, 0);
    uint8_t len, ide;
    int txId = func(&cmd, reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(payload.data()), &len, &ide);
    QCanBusFrame txFrame = QCanBusFrame(txId, payload);
    _can->sendFrame(txFrame);
}
```

Invoke normally as `pack_CMD(cmd1, func1)`, letting the compiler deduce `T` and `U`.

You can also pass the function as a compile-time non-type template argument, e.g. like so:

```
template<auto Fn, typename T>
void SEMTools::pack_CMD(T cmd)
{
    QByteArray payload(8, 0);
    uint8_t len, ide;
    int txId = Fn(&cmd, reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(payload.data()), &len, &ide);
    QCanBusFrame txFrame = QCanBusFrame(txId, payload);
    _can->sendFrame(txFrame);
}
```

Invoke as `pack_CMD<&Pack_CT_CMD_can>(cmd1)`.